# How to get artifact build version in ymal json via pipeline build Id

Tags: powershell, yaml, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on a Ymal pipeline where I'm consuming build artifact from another pipeline.I'm able to download artifact using below code:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0  

   inputs:       

   buildType:specific 

   project: Test Project 

   pipeline: TestInfrastructure-Rel

   branchName: 'refs/heads/release/preview'  

   downloadType: 'single'

   artifactName: Testartifact Packages

   buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'

   downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

In above code I know I can  set property buildId to get build id  via this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Though I want to know what is the package version.I'm using this API to get information from the particular build but artifact version number is not coming up.
[https://dev.azure.com/{Org](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrg) name}/{Project name}/_apis/build/builds/{buildid}/timeline/?api-version=5.1

Basically I have to create a report on daily basis based on the specific pipeline run where I will need all the information.

I also would like to inform you I have package version in the pipeline via resource though I am not able to set it in to a variable. If i set package version in any variable its not showing in the build pipeline ymal json. when I run the API using the [https://dev.azure.com/{Org](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrg) name}/{Project name}/_apis/build/builds/{buildid}/timeline/?api-version=5.1 I am not seeing any package version in side below task in the image. If we can set version from ymal pipeline from any property or anything so that I can get that version here in below image.

[image]

If anyone can help me or guide how I can set or pass version number using variable or any other property in PowerShell or azure PowerShell task that would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pipeline sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-resource) to consuming build artifact from another pipeline. Then you can get the artifact build version by referencing to the predefined variable `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName`. See below example:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: sourcepipeline  # can be any string, this is the Alias in the predefined variables. identifier for the resource used in pipeline resource variables
    project: Test Project # project for the source; optional for current project
    source: TestInfrastructure-Rel  # name of the pipeline that produces an artifact
    branch: refs/heads/release/preview

pool: 
  vmImage: vs2017-win2016

steps:
- powershell: |
     echo "$(resources.pipeline.sourcepipeline.runName)"  #get the artifact build number
     echo "$(resources.pipeline.sourcepipeline.runId)"    #get the artifact build id
```

To consume the artifacts defined in the pipeline source. You just need to add the download task in your yaml pipeline. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#download).

```
- download: sourcepipeline
```

Artifacts from the associated pipeline resource are downloaded to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/<pipeline resource identifier>/`.

If you want use the `DownloadBuildArtifacts` task and rest api to get the artifact build number. You can call [Build get rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). After you get the buildNumber, you can set it to a variable using [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) `##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildVersion]<buildVersion>`.  See below example:

```
- powershell: |
        $url = $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/<build.id>?api-version=5.1"

        $rawResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"}
        
        #pass build number to a variable 
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildVersion]$($rawResponse.buildNumber)"
```

Update:

You can use the [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#logissue-log-an-error-or-warning) to log a warning. And set the package version to be the warning message. Then the package version will show up in the timeline rest api. see below:

Add a powershell task to run the logging commands:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
      echo "##vso[task.logissue type=warning]$(resources.pipeline.sourcepipeline.runName)"
```

Then you will see the package version in the yaml json as below:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm doing the same as you mentioned $(resources.pipeline.sourcepipeline.runName) my problem is that when I am setting package version  in the variable its not coming up in ymal json.  I tried the same way you mentioned echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildVersion]$($rawResponse.buildNumber)" though I could't see buildVersion variable in ymal json when I run this API https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/build/builds/1234/timeline/?api-version=5.1 your buildVersion should come here in PowerShell task but I don't see it.

Comment: I didnot really understand why you tried to get the package version showing up in the yaml json. I am afraid the `timeline` rest api cannot get the variables evaluated in side a  task. If you want to get the variable's value. You can try output the variable in the script task and then use `Builds - Get Build Log` rest api to get the task log.

Comment: @GauravJoshi If you try reviewing the package version in a convenient way rather then open the build summary log. You can try update the Update your buildnumber using the log command `echo ##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(resources.pipeline.sourcepipeline.runName)`. In this way you can see the package version directly at the build run name.

Comment: I am trying to generate report like this where I have to display publish package version in one of the column. For this I tried multiple things I just want to get variable value in ymal json which I'm not getting I don't want to use that variable value in subsequent task. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/whXEn.png

Comment: @GauravJoshi I have a workaround to show the package version in the yaml json returned by the timeline rest api. check above update.

Comment: thank you for your all the response really appreciated. I followed the same as you suggested and it worked. Though I got an idea from your code and I made some change according to my needs                                                                         
 - powershell: |
      displayName: TestPublish_Preview_PackageVersion           
       "-$(resources.pipeline._TestProjRel_Preview.runName)"